# constructing a universal cover from K(G,1) space

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

Let G be a torsion-free group and G' a group of finite index. Suppose G' has finite cohomological dimension. Then it has a finite-dimensional K(G',1) complex. Its universal cover X' is also finite-dimensional, and it is a contractible free G'-complex. What can we do to construct a finite-dimensional, contractible free G-complex from X'? What I am reading says that X, as a set, can be defined as Hom$_{G'}(G,X')$, but I don't really see this. This is in the context of Serre's theorem about virtual cohomological dimension.